# C# WPF Draw equilateral polygons programatically

Tags: c#, wpf, polygon

I'm working on a method to programatically draw equilateral polygon shapes in C#, WPF. But I have been stuck and I can't solve calculating the angles. Where is the problem? How should I correct this? I have given the public int, R(radius) a value of 100.

```
private Path EquilateralPolygon(int sides)
    {
        //Centering
        Point center = new Point(canvasSize.Width / 2, canvasSize.Height / 2);

        PathFigure myPathFigure = new PathFigure();

        int alfa = 360 / sides;
        int[] angles = new int[6];
        for (int i = 0; i < sides; i++)
            angles[i] = 360 - alfa * i;

        MessageBox.Show(angles.Sum().ToString());

        Point A = new Point(center.X, center.Y - R);

        myPathFigure.StartPoint = A;
        PolyLineSegment myLineSegment = new PolyLineSegment();
        for (int i = 1; i < sides; i++)
        {
            myLineSegment.Points.Add(new Point(center.X + Math.Cos(angles[i]) * R, center.Y + Math.Sin(angles[i]) * R));
        }

        myLineSegment.Points.Add(A);

        PathSegmentCollection myPathSegmentCollection = new PathSegmentCollection();
        myPathSegmentCollection.Add(myLineSegment);

        myPathFigure.Segments = myPathSegmentCollection;

        PathFigureCollection myPathFigureCollection = new PathFigureCollection();
        myPathFigureCollection.Add(myPathFigure);

        PathGeometry myPathGeometry = new PathGeometry();
        myPathGeometry.Figures = myPathFigureCollection;

        Path myPath = new Path();
        myPath.Stroke = Brushes.Red;
        myPath.StrokeThickness = 1;
        myPath.Data = myPathGeometry;

        return myPath;

    }
```

Comment: //I have at most 6 points, so that's why the array set to that.//

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've posted a lot of code and were not specific about how it's not working, so there may be more than one issue with your code. However, one big issue is that the [`Math.Cos`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.cos.aspx) (and related trig methods) take the angle in the form of [radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian), not degrees as you have them.

> Parameters
>
> ```
> d
> ```
>
> Type: System.Double An angle, **measured in radians**.

You will need to convert them to radians. To convert, multiply by π (available via [`Math.PI`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.pi.aspx)) then divide by 180 degrees.

```
myLineSegment.Points.Add(
    new Point(center.X + Math.Cos(angles[i] * Math.PI / 180.0) * R, 
    center.Y + Math.Sin(angles[i] * Math.PI / 180) * R));
```

---

EDIT: In addition to the radians/degrees issue, I can see you may be experiencing integer truncation, both in the use of your `angles` array and your calculation of `alfa`. I would suggest you try changing your use of integers to `double` so that your code works fine with fractions of a degree.

Comment: Oh, that's a lot of help, I didn't know that. Thank you!

Comment: @Tigris: You're welcome. I've just edited my answer with another possible issue with your use of integer division.